# React Native - How to Build an Image Grid like FaceBook

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am looking to create an app using React Native and need a list of images to be arranged and displayed just like facebook activity photos.

In short, I want to create the react-native version of 
https://taras-d.github.io/images-grid/

Does anyone know a RN Component that offers something similar ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create image grid yourself by setting width height for each image and render it in a row.

For example, You want 3 images for 1 row. You can use dimensions to get windows width and divide for 3.

```
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
var IMAGES_PER_ROW = 3;

calculatedSize(){
  var size = windowWidth / IMAGES_PER_ROW
  return {width: size, height: size}
}
```

After that, we will render images in a row.

```
renderRow(images) {
    return images.map((uri,i) =>{
      return(
        <Image key={i} style={[styles.item, this.calculatedSize()]} source={{uri: uri}} />
      );
    })
  }
  renderImagesInGroupsOf(count) {
    return _.chunk(IMAGE_URLS, IMAGES_PER_ROW).map((imagesForRow,i) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.row} key={i}>
          {this.renderRow(imagesForRow)}
        </View>
      )
    })
  }
```

You can set image grid margin like you want in `styles.item` like `margin: 1`.

Full example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/vFKTXw/raw_file?file=index.android.js)

Comment: Thanks. This seems to do the trick !

Comment: The link for full example seems broken now.

Comment: Full example link is not working, can you update it with new link ?